# Destroy a Headquarter without shooting it?

Tags: boom-beach

Is it possible to destroy a HQ with only shooting all the other buildings?

Reason for this question: The HQ receives damage, if other non-defense buildings get destroyed. I read the following rule and asked me, if this would be a rare possibility: ["When a building in your base is destroyed, the Headquarters receives 10% of the building's max health as damage."](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Headquarters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer for this from the [this](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Headquarters) wiki:

- When all of the Buildings on a base except for the HQ are destroyed, the HQ will have 30% health remaining. 70% Damage / Number of Buildings = Damage per building.
  This means, If you have 7 buildings, you will receive 10% HQ-damage per destroyed one.

Comment: And just for the record, if you damage the HQ enough first (attacking it), then you can finish it destroying only other buildings.